# Using a custom renderer in PCL library

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library, custom-renderer

I want to use my custom renderer inside a PCL. Is it possible? Or can I initialize my custom renderer inside this PCL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've found a solution.
I've just created a class in my PCL and used it in XAML, let's say:

```
public class MyHelperEntry : Entry { public MyHelperEntry() { } }
```

that inherits `Entry` class. And in an App, where I use this PCL, I've created a class, that inherits MyHelperEntry:

```
public CustomHelperEntry : MyHelperEntry { public CustomHelperEntry() { } }
```

and used this `CustomHelperEntry` as a custom renderer.

Answer (score 1):

No and No.

What you use in PCL is - let's say - component and it's abstraction. The 'materialization' (or not) of the component will be made by custom renders on each platform.

I can't see a reason to use it on a platform-independent implementation once it can be shown (or to behaves) differently on each one.

> Custom Renderers let developers override this process to customize the appearance and behavior of Xamarin.Forms controls on each platform.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/

Maybe with a real case, we can suggest another solution.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

I've just wanted to do a common staff for several apps (for example, settings activity). I did this with custom renderers for one app, and in another app i need to use the same settings. And i don't want to copy-past the source code. Maybe you could suggest any solutions for such an issue?..

Comment: @ДенисЧорный It sounds like a package or a personal plugin/toolkit. You can do it too. [Here's a good video about this topic from James Montemagno's youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eCmgy7TQd00).

Comment: Added a solution